# Loop on multiple mongoose docs within if statment - Discord embed message

Tags: javascript, mongoose, foreach, discord.js

I'm working on a discortd bot, the full following code works but I would like to add a loop in order to show all documents in lmy embed message.

I know I have to loop somehow but I can't seem to get my head around it. Any ideas ?

```
const { SlashCommandBuilder, EmbedBuilder } = require('discord.js');

const tiny = require("tiny-json-http");
const date = require('date-and-time');

const Calls = require('../calls.js');
const mongoose = require("mongoose");
mongoose.connect('mongodb+srv://*****:*******@*******.ilnqf.mongodb.net/*******?retryWrites=true&w=majority');

module.exports = {
    data: new SlashCommandBuilder()
        .setName('open')
        .setDescription('CHECK YOUR OPEN POSITIONS'),
    async execute(interaction) {
        try {
            const doc = await Calls.find({ userID: interaction.user.id });
                Calls.countDocuments({ username: interaction.user.username, closeTime: '' })
                    .then((count) => {
                        console.log('COUNT: ' + count);
                        Calls.find({ userID: interaction.user.id, closeTime: '' })
                        .then((find) => {
                            if (count == 0) {
                                const embed = new EmbedBuilder()
                                    .setDescription(`<@${interaction.user.id}>, has no open position.`)
                                    .setColor(0x674EA7)
                                    .setTimestamp(Date.now())
                                interaction.reply({ embeds: [embed] });
                            } else if (count == 1) {
                                const coin = find[0]['coin'];
                                const position = find[0]['callType'];
                                const embed = new EmbedBuilder()
                                    .setDescription(`<@${interaction.user.id}>, has a total of __${count} open position__.`)
                                    .setColor(0x674EA7)
                                    .setTimestamp(Date.now())
                                interaction.reply({ embeds: [embed] });
                            } else {  
                                const coin = find[0]['coin'];
                                const position = find[0]['callType'];
                                const embed = new EmbedBuilder()
                                    .setDescription(`<@${interaction.user.id}>, has a total of __${count} open position(s)__.`)
                                    .setColor(0x674EA7)
                                    .setTimestamp(Date.now())
                                    .addFields(
                                        { name: '**TOKEN**', value: `${coin}` + '', inline: true },
                                        { name: '**POSITION**', value: `${position}` + '', inline: true },
                                        //{ name: '**TOKEN**', value: `${coin}` + '', inline: true }, ==> Doc 2
                                        //{ name: '**POSITION**', value: `${position}` + '', inline: true }, ==> Doc 2
                                        // { name: '**TOKEN**', value: `${coin}` + '', inline: true }, ==> Doc 3
                                        //{ name: '**POSITION**', value: `${position}` + '', inline: true } ==> Doc 3
                                    );
                                interaction.reply({ embeds: [embed] });
                            }
                         })
                        .catch((err) => console.log(err));
                    })
                    .catch((err) => console.log(err));
        } catch (error) {
            console.log(error);
        }
        
    },

};
```

Thanks in advance,

I can't seem to find the way to compile all documents to show each data in my embed message.

Comment: Ok I'm starting to have something here but weird is that it's giving me twice the same result instead of giving the 2 docs I have in BDD

` find.forEach(docs => {
                                        const coin = find[0]['coin'];
                                        const position = find[0]['callType'];
                                    embed.addFields(
                                        { name: '**POSITION**', value: '**TOKEN: **' + `${coin}` + ' | **POSITION: **' + `${position}` + '', inline: false },
);
});
interaction.reply({ embeds: [embed] })`

Comment: Ok I've solved it. ;)

`doc.forEach(docs => {
                                        const coin = docs['coin'];
                                        const position = docs['callType'];
                                    embed.addFields(
                                        { name: '**POSITION**', value: '**TOKEN: **' + `${coin}` + ' | **POSITION: **' + `${position}` + '', inline: false },
                                    );
                                    });`